# How to improve the performance of Isolation forest on time series?

Tags: time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I'm using Isolation Forest on a time series. I'm trying to classify faults in sensor data, but Isolation forest is not functioning quite like I would like. The picture shows how a lot of the jumps are not detected. [image]

I am looking for tips on how to improve the fault detection? For instance with features that could be added or parameter changes? I also read somewhere that using rolling windows could help, but I am not sure exactly how?

I'm also interested in general tips when using isolation forests.

Comment: What is your definition of an anomaly/outlier?

Comment: The jumps and notches in the graph. For instance at approximately (8000,8) and (65000,5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The features you use must reflect the kind of anomalies you wish to detect. In your case, you define anomalies as large jumps in values within a short time span. For this, you should transform the input data into differences - and use that as input to the anomaly detection method.
The easiest is to compute difference between consecutive values, using something like [numpy.ediff1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html). For a more general solution, consider computing windows of a small amount of datapoints, and compute max-min inside each window, and use that as the feature.

Also, for univariate continious problems like this, there are more suitable anomaly methods than Isolation Forest. A simple transform like Z-score or Median Absolute Deviation. In scikit-learn [EllipticEnvelope](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.html#sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope) is one alternative.

Comment: Thank you. When computing windows with a small amount of datapoints, how many points do you suggest? The total data is 78000 points. Also, do you mean using both the max and the minimum value as a feature each?

Comment: If you _only_ care about changes, then use max-min (difference) as the feature. If you also want to catch extreme values, then you can add max, min also.

Comment: How many datapoints / time-period to use is problem/task specific. Set it based on what you know of the problem, or use a labeled validation set and formulate a cost function that can be optimized with hyperparameter optimization.

Comment: Okay I understand. When using max,min together with difference as a feature, they would have to be the same size right? Since max,min will be length(timeseries) - window_size, it will be window_size - 1 elements shorter than the difference feature. How should I deal with this?

Comment: Compute all features on the windows. Skip windows where full  features cannot be computed (at edges). These are your instances for the model.